# Requirements to have PayPal Reference Transactions enabled

Tags: paypal, reference, transactions, express-checkout

For a new project we are looking for a payment system that allows to use a single user authorization for charging their credit card multiple times over a long period of time. PayPal's Reference Transactions seem a great fit, however before we plunge into implementation a few things should be clarified. One of them is:

**What exactly is required from a Merchant to have Reference Transactions  enabled?**

We do not want to complete the integration to find out that we do not meet the requirements, [as suggested here](https://www.angelleye.com/paypal-recurring-payments-reference-transactions-and-preapproved-payments/). We are waiting for response from PayPal MTS but... well... it has been already a week...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Paypal MTS team has no permission to enable Reference transaction. Plz contact Paypal customer service to enable it.Customer service contact Phone is [here](http://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_contact-phone).

Comment: Thanks. Yup, MTS does not turn it on - Customer Service can. After some message channeling we've finally got the answer that there has to be a decent amount of sales happening to get Reference Transactions enabled. We, as a fresh project, are not eligible :/